# Cannot read properties of undefined reading constructor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I am using twitter boostrap 3.1 , I replaced  bootstrap  css  and js file  with twitter bootstrap  version 5.1. But after that I am getting an error  in bootstrap-editable.js file as 'Cannot read properties of undefined reading constructor'. looking for  the help to fix.

```
    $.extend($.fn.editableContainer.Popup.prototype, {
    containerName: 'popover',
    containerDataName: 'bs.popover',
    innerCss: '.popover-content',
    defaults: $.fn.popover.Constructor.DEFAULTS,
 initContainer: function () {
            $.extend(this.containerOptions, {
                trigger: 'manual',
                selector: false,
                content: ' ',
                template: this.defaults.template
            });
```

Comment: Bootstrap 3 and 5 are very different. There have been [multiple migrations](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/migration/). The components are no longer jQuery plugins so the code above isn't going to work in Bootstrap 5.